The library resulting from obfuscation cannot be read in the Gradle project
I'm trying to make a program using Netbeans 21 + Jdk 17 with Project Gradle
This program has a dependency on another project. This project has been obfuscated using Proguard 7.4.2
the obfuscation process that I do is

downlad the source code from https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard.mirror/files/v7.4.2/7.4.2%20source%20code.zip/download
Then build using Netbeans 21 Jdk 17, the results are in the lib folder like:

proguard.jar
proguard-ant.jar
proguardgui.jar
retrace


run proguargui.jar
java -jar D:\lib\proguardgui.jar

by using the Coba.pro file, here are the contents of the file
note: I copied the rt.jar file from Jdk 7
    -injars JvsDistCoreHql\target\DistCoreHql.jar
-outjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\corehql-2.4.jar

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\antlr4-runtime-4.13.0.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\aspectjweaver-1.9.22.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\byte-buddy-1.14.11.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\classmate-1.5.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.0.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jandex-3.1.2.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.13.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\modelentity-2.4.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\logback-core-1.4.14.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\micrometer-commons-1.12.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\micrometer-observation-1.12.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\slf4j-api-2.0.2.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\snakeyaml-2.2.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-aop-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-aspects-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-beans-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-context-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-core-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-data-commons-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-data-jpa-3.2.5.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-expression-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-jcl-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-jdbc-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-orm-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-tx-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-web-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.20.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar
-libraryjars JvsDistCoreHql\target\lib\txw2-4.0.2.jar

-useuniqueclassmembernames
-repackageclasses ''



# Keep names - Native method names. Keep all native class/method names.
-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main' methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Keep - Libraries. Keep all public and protected classes, fields, and methods.
-keep public class * {
    public protected <fields>;
    public protected <methods>;
}

# Also keep - Enumerations. Keep the special static methods that are required in
# enumeration classes.
-keepclassmembers enum  * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

# Also keep - Swing UI L&F. Keep all extensions of javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI,
# along with the special 'createUI' method.
-keep class * extends javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI {
    public static javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI createUI(javax.swing.JComponent);
}

# Remove - System method calls. Remove all invocations of System
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.System {
    public static long currentTimeMillis();
    static java.lang.Class getCallerClass();
    public static int identityHashCode(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.SecurityManager getSecurityManager();
    public static java.util.Properties getProperties();
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getenv(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String mapLibraryName(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.String getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
}

# Remove - Math method calls. Remove all invocations of Math
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.Math {
    public static double sin(double);
    public static double cos(double);
    public static double tan(double);
    public static double asin(double);
    public static double acos(double);
    public static double atan(double);
    public static double toRadians(double);
    public static double toDegrees(double);
    public static double exp(double);
    public static double log(double);
    public static double log10(double);
    public static double sqrt(double);
    public static double cbrt(double);
    public static double IEEEremainder(double,double);
    public static double ceil(double);
    public static double floor(double);
    public static double rint(double);
    public static double atan2(double,double);
    public static double pow(double,double);
    public static int round(float);
    public static long round(double);
    public static double random();
    public static int abs(int);
    public static long abs(long);
    public static float abs(float);
    public static double abs(double);
    public static int max(int,int);
    public static long max(long,long);
    public static float max(float,float);
    public static double max(double,double);
    public static int min(int,int);
    public static long min(long,long);
    public static float min(float,float);
    public static double min(double,double);
    public static double ulp(double);
    public static float ulp(float);
    public static double signum(double);
    public static float signum(float);
    public static double sinh(double);
    public static double cosh(double);
    public static double tanh(double);
    public static double hypot(double,double);
    public static double expm1(double);
    public static double log1p(double);
}

# Remove - Number method calls. Remove all invocations of Number
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.* extends java.lang.Number {
    public static java.lang.String toString(byte);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(byte);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String);
    public static byte parseByte(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Byte valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Byte decode(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Byte);
    public static java.lang.String toString(short);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String);
    public static short parseShort(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Short valueOf(short);
    public static java.lang.Short decode(java.lang.String);
    public static short reverseBytes(short);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Short);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(int);
    public static java.lang.String toString(int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String,int);
    public static int parseInt(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Integer getInteger(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.Integer decode(java.lang.String);
    public static int highestOneBit(int);
    public static int lowestOneBit(int);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(int);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(int);
    public static int bitCount(int);
    public static int rotateLeft(int,int);
    public static int rotateRight(int,int);
    public static int reverse(int);
    public static int signum(int);
    public static int reverseBytes(int);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Integer);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long,int);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toOctalString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toBinaryString(long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(long);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String,int);
    public static long parseLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long valueOf(long);
    public static java.lang.Long decode(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,long);
    public static java.lang.Long getLong(java.lang.String,java.lang.Long);
    public static long highestOneBit(long);
    public static long lowestOneBit(long);
    public static int numberOfLeadingZeros(long);
    public static int numberOfTrailingZeros(long);
    public static int bitCount(long);
    public static long rotateLeft(long,int);
    public static long rotateRight(long,int);
    public static long reverse(long);
    public static int signum(long);
    public static long reverseBytes(long);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Long);
    public static java.lang.String toString(float);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(float);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Float valueOf(float);
    public static float parseFloat(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(float);
    public static boolean isInfinite(float);
    public static int floatToIntBits(float);
    public static int floatToRawIntBits(float);
    public static float intBitsToFloat(int);
    public static int compare(float,float);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Float);
    public static java.lang.String toString(double);
    public static java.lang.String toHexString(double);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(java.lang.String);
    public static java.lang.Double valueOf(double);
    public static double parseDouble(java.lang.String);
    public static boolean isNaN(double);
    public static boolean isInfinite(double);
    public static long doubleToLongBits(double);
    public static long doubleToRawLongBits(double);
    public static double longBitsToDouble(long);
    public static int compare(double,double);
    public boolean isNaN();
    public boolean isInfinite();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Double);
    public <init>(byte);
    public <init>(short);
    public <init>(int);
    public <init>(long);
    public <init>(float);
    public <init>(double);
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
    public byte byteValue();
    public short shortValue();
    public int intValue();
    public long longValue();
    public float floatValue();
    public double doubleValue();
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public int hashCode();
    public java.lang.String toString();
}

# Remove - String method calls. Remove all invocations of String
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.String {
    public <init>();
    public <init>(byte[]);
    public <init>(byte[],int);
    public <init>(byte[],int,int);
    public <init>(byte[],int,int,int);
    public <init>(byte[],int,int,java.lang.String);
    public <init>(byte[],java.lang.String);
    public <init>(char[]);
    public <init>(char[],int,int);
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
    public <init>(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String copyValueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(boolean);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[]);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(char[],int,int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(double);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(float);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(int);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(java.lang.Object);
    public static java.lang.String valueOf(long);
    public boolean contentEquals(java.lang.StringBuffer);
    public boolean endsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
    public boolean matches(java.lang.String);
    public boolean regionMatches(boolean,int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String);
    public boolean startsWith(java.lang.String,int);
    public byte[] getBytes();
    public byte[] getBytes(java.lang.String);
    public char charAt(int);
    public char[] toCharArray();
    public int compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.Object);
    public int compareTo(java.lang.String);
    public int hashCode();
    public int indexOf(int);
    public int indexOf(int,int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int);
    public int lastIndexOf(int,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.CharSequence subSequence(int,int);
    public java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String replace(char,char);
    public java.lang.String replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String);
    public java.lang.String[] split(java.lang.String,int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase();
    public java.lang.String toLowerCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase();
    public java.lang.String toUpperCase(java.util.Locale);
    public java.lang.String trim();
}

# Remove - StringBuffer method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuffer
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuffer {
    public <init>();
    public <init>(int);
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
    public <init>(java.lang.CharSequence);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}

# Remove - StringBuilder method calls. Remove all invocations of StringBuilder
# methods without side effects whose return values are not used.
-assumenosideeffects public class java.lang.StringBuilder {
    public <init>();
    public <init>(int);
    public <init>(java.lang.String);
    public <init>(java.lang.CharSequence);
    public java.lang.String toString();
    public char charAt(int);
    public int capacity();
    public int codePointAt(int);
    public int codePointBefore(int);
    public int indexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String);
    public int lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,int);
    public int length();
    public java.lang.String substring(int);
    public java.lang.String substring(int,int);
}

the obfuscation process was successful.
then the result is the corehql-2.4.jar file which I use in another project

Open the SpringBootTest project using Gradle

Copy the corehql-2.4.jar file to the Gradle project in the libs folder

add depecencies in the build.gradle file
 buildscript {
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.0")
 }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
 mavenLocal()
 maven { url "https://mavensync.zkoss.org/maven2" }
 maven { url "https://mavensync.zkoss.org/eval" }
 mavenCentral()

     flatDir {
         dirs("libs")
     }

}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

ext {
zkspringbootVersion    ='3.0.0'
zkVersion              ='10.0.0-jakarta'
zatsVersion            ='4.0.0'
junitVersion           ='4.13.1'
}
configurations.testImplementation {
// conflicts with ZATS (which is using jetty)
exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
dependencies {

             implementation ("org.zkoss.zkspringboot:zkspringboot-starter:${zkspringbootVersion}")
             implementation "org.zkoss.zk:zk:${zkVersion}"      
             implementation "org.zkoss.zk:zkplus:${zkVersion}"
             implementation "org.zkoss.zk:zkbind:${zkVersion}"
             implementation "org.zkoss.zk:zul:${zkVersion}"
             implementation "org.zkoss.zk:zhtml:${zkVersion}"
             implementation 'org.zkoss.zk:zkplus-legacy:9.5.0'  
             implementation "org.zkoss.common:zel:${zkVersion}"            
             implementation "org.zkoss.common:zcommon:${zkVersion}"        
             implementation "org.zkoss.common:zweb:${zkVersion}"           
             implementation "org.zkoss.common:zweb-dsp:${zkVersion}"
             testImplementation "org.zkoss.zats:zats-mimic-ext96:${zatsVersion}"

          implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.2.5'
              implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.2.5'
              implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:3.0.0'
              implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:3.2.5'     
              implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.2.5'

              implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.4.2.Final'
              implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.3'                       
              implementation 'com.guardsquare:proguard-base:7.4.2'

              //library my sub project  
              implementation files('libs/modelentity.jar')

              //file .jar result obfusction
              implementation files('libs/corehql-2.4.jar')
    }


run project / bootRun

input data then save, and get error
java.lang.VerifyError: Constructor must call super() or this() before return
Exception Details:
Location:
com/myproject/core/dao/hql/master/HqlCompanyDao.()V @0: return
Reason:
Error exists in the bytecode
Bytecode:
0000000: b1


this class in project CoreHql
class HqlCompanyDao.java

import com.myproject.hibernate.model.Company;
import com.myproject.hibernate.model.Person;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class HqlCompanyDao {
        
    public Company getCompanyCode(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
       Company company=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Company",Company.class).uniqueResult();
       return infoCompany;
    }
    
    public void savePerson(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Person person){
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(person);
    }
    
}

thank you so much for your help

solved, with add -optimizations optimize.conservatively https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/702/ thanks all
